# crontab settings with start_time and interval

Tags: cron

I have a linux cron job to run. I want to configure its setting. What I have is, `start_time` for the job and `interval` after which it should repeat every time. `interval` is integer and has unit of day. So for example, I want to set up cron job starting on some random date in future and want to run that job periodically after every `interval` days. I tried to do `0 0 * * */interval` but it does not give what I want. Any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want something like

```
0 0 */interval * * /your/command
```

Basically switching day of week for day of the month. As for the random start date, that will have to be done somewhere else I think, like with a shell script which edits the cron file at a certain point etc.

EDIT:
This little script would allow you to edit the cron file.

```
#!/bin/sh
crontab -l > tempcron
echo "00 00 * * * /bin/ls" >> tempcron #just an example cron
crontab tempcron
rm tempcron
```

Comment: I tried this solution as well but it does not care about `start_time`. It sets job from 1st day of each month. I am more interested in changing starting time of cron. Can you give example of shell script which you mentioned to edit cron file?

Comment: Yeah you can't edit the start time of a cron job using cron itself, it's intended just for setting up a regular action starting at the next instance based on the parameters.
I'm not entirely what you're looking for in terms of start - how far into the future are you looking? Obviously leaving a shell script running a loop for days until it hits the right time doesn't make a lot of sense, but you could maybe do something like have a script which checks if the time matches a stored value and if it does then edits the cron file. Then run THAT regularly in cron until the time has passed

Comment: I've added an edit with a script that would edit the cron file for you. Difficult to say how you would want to do the random start without knowing more, but if you for example got the current timestamp using `date`, checked if it had passed a certain predefined value, and if it has then run the function in my edit then that may achieve what you wanted? You could set that script up in cron running every hour or whatever and then have it populate cron from a premade cron file which would get rid of this initial script (hope that makes sense)

Comment: Actually, start time and interval are user-inputs in my case. So both of them are random variables. I have understood that keeping everything random is not going to work with crontab. So I am thinking to apply limits on `interval` input value. I am going to allow `interval` to be 1, 7 or 30 days. But even in that case `start_time` could be any random future date depending on user input.

Comment: Hmmm yeah sounds like a tricky use-case for cron here. Whatever you come out with will be a little hacky. If it was me I think I'd look at storing the user inputs (i.e. start time and command) in a file, then have a cron job running a script which loops through each line of the file, checking if the date has arrived yet, and when it has it would run something like the snippet in my answer to add that command to the cron file before deleting the relevant line from the user file (that could be tricky though but there are ways to do that).